# Обводка вокруг PNG с прозрачностью в TCPDF

Tags: pdf, png, tcpdf

При выводе PNG картинки с прозрачностью через TCPDF возникает серая граница на стыке прозрачности.

[image: картинка в pdf]

Оригинальная картинка границ не имеет

[image: оригинал]

Как это можно побороть?

Answer (score 1):

возможно, конфигурации какието.

Скорее всего, связано с тем, что при изменении размера -  начинают дорисовыватся бордюры.

Знающие советуют добавить 8-ми битную маску.
[пример альфа канала](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_042.phps)

сам не пробовал, но пример с официального сайта должен помочь.

Comment: Картинку вывожу один в один без изменений размера. Разрешение у нее 300dpi, как и значение по-умолчанию. Т.е. по идее никаких трансформаций с картинкой производиться не должно.
В англоязычной части пишут что это может быть особенности вьюера, которым я пдфку смотрю, но проверял в разных вьювера и на разных компах - везде есть, только разной степени выраженности.

Из всего что перекопал по инету, есть только упоминание что на альфа канале tcpdf выставляет не 8бит а 7бит и поэтому могут быть артефакты. Но не понятно правда ли это и как это лечить.

Вырубку маской попробую, спасибо.

Comment: В итоге убрал прозрачность у картинки и сделал маску через RoundedRect.

Answer (score 0):

Тоже столкнулись с подобной проблемой при печати документации. Хорошее решение найти не смогли, в итоге просто вместо прозрачности делаем белую подложку на все картинки в графическом редакторе.

С белым фоном проблемы с обводкой нет, но это костыль. На тот момент решение было принято и далее не менялось.

Накануне меня опять озадачили рисованием PDF документов, стал смотреть что с этой темой - нашел вот этот пост.

Посмотрите в сторону https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/master/CHANGELOG.TXT

Новая версия еще в разработке, но судя по Changelog:
6.2.11 (2015-08-02)
    - Bug #1070 "PNG regression in 6.2.9 (they appear as their alpha channel)" was fixed.

Попробуйте создать документ с новой версией библиотеки, с GitHub. Я попробовал - рамок нет (или я их не вижу).

Comment: Это фактически не является ответом на вопрос. Если у вас есть другие вопросы, вы можете задать их нажав кнопку «[Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Дополнительно вы можете [добавить вознаграждение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties), чтобы привлечь к вопросу больше внимания, когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет достаточного уровня. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/174443)

Comment: Да, виноват, исправил и дополнил